# Find execution time for parallel programs in matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I have written parallel program for HYPR sequential algorithm  which basically reconstructs medical image in matalb. I want to know how to find the execution time of parallel program in matlab. I tried with tic and toc. But i get different execution time whenever i run the program.

Comment: Then maybe the execution time *is* different each time?  Please explain further: are you trying to measure the time for your whole program to run?  Why would it make a different if it was parallel?  How do `tic` and `toc` not do what you expected?

Answer (score 2):

Try [MATLAB's profiler](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) with the built-in functionality of [profiling parallel code](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/distcomp/profiling-parallel-code.html).